# Uninitialized local variable 'lc' used but I initialized it

Tags: c++, initialization

I wanted to check whether what I wrote on the programming exam was working at least. And it turned out that it was not. And I do not understand why EXACTLY it does not work.

The task was to write a program with boolean function which should return true state if 2d matrix has only one row which consist entirely of negative element.
Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

bool cns();
const int n=5;
int a[n][n];

bool cns() {
    int ts;
    //!!!!
    int lc; //!! I have initiated lc variable but still it does not work !!
    //!!!
    //standard 2d static quad matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << "a[" << i << "][" << j << "]=" << endl;
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }
    //check whether the sum of elements of the row is negative or not
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ts = 0; //temp sum
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            ts += a[i][j]; //I thought what if sum of elements is negative then the whole row is negative too
            if (ts < 0) { //I have just realized that is wrong
                lc++; //counter of negative lines, which consist entirely of negative elements
            }
        }
    }
    //only one row should be whole negative
    if (lc == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int lc;
    cout << cns << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So could you tell me please where I did mistake with variable 'lc' and why compiler tells me "uninitialized local variable 'lc' used"?

Comment: You've only declared it, but you never actually initialize it. Write `int lc{};` to declare and initialize with zero at the same time.

Comment: Writing a comment, that you initialized it, does not initialize it. You also did not call your function, you print the address: `cout << cns << endl;` ==> `cout << cns() << endl;`

Comment: @mch Thank you for correcting me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialising a variable is, essentially, giving it an initial value.

Your definition of `lc`

```
int lc;
```

does not initialise it.   Since it is a variable of automatic storage duration (i.e. it is local to a block), it is not initialised.

Accessing its value therefore gives undefined behaviour.

The first thing that the code does with `lc` (within the first set of loops in your code) is

```
lc++;
```

Incrementing a variable of type `int` requires accessing its value, before producing an effect (doing the act of incrementing).   Hence undefined behaviour.

The compiler warning is being issued because of that.  To eliminate the warning, either initialise it where it is defined.  For example;

```
int lc = 42;
```

or ensure the first operation is to set it to a valid value

```
int lc;

 //  later on the first thing ever done to lc is ...

lc = 47;
```

People often assume that all variables (of basic types, like `int`) which are defined without being explicitly initialised will have an initial value of `0` (zero).    That is true in some other languages, but not in C++ - at least not in this context (an `int` of `static` storage duration IS zero-initialised).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't *initialized* `lc`, but *declared* it.

To initialize a variable means giving it an initial value (which you should always do):

```
int lc = 0;
```

Comment: The statement *is* a declaration, but more to the point, it is also a *definition*.  (Of course, with block-scope variables there is no way to declare them without defining them - but the difference between *declaration* and *definition* comes up often enough that it is worth being pedantic about this.)

Comment: @MartinBonner Agree.

Answer (score 0):

*Initialization* is **not** what you have done here. As stated by amc176 you have only *declared* it.

When you *declare* variable `lc`, memory is reserved on the stack. The amount of memory reserved depends on the data type (a `char` will take up more memory than an `int`).

However, if you do not provide an initial value for that variable (i.e. *initialize* it) the initial value of the data type will be exactly what was present in that specific piece of memory. That is why your compiler is complaining.

Comment: "a `char` will take up more memory than an `int`", are you sure about that? Your last paragraph is not necessarily true. It can have a trap representation or an indeterminate value. The behaviour is undefined.